# Changing Dom to Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, dom

Hi I was just wondering if anyone could help me find an equivalent function for dom values to convert it into Jquery.

If I have a code in DOM format:

```
var x = document.querySelector('#x');
```

what would give me the same value back but in Jquery form ?

A different example I have would be for event listeners, How would I take this example and transform it into Jquery so they work hand in hand and have no signs of DOM.

ex:

```
function onmouseup(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
   //random code
  }
c.addEventListener('mouseup', onmouseup, false);
```

any help would be great!

Comment: `$('#x')` and `$(c).on('mouseup', onmouseup)` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For jQuery you can write.

```
var x = $('#x');

x.mouseup(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();


});
```

Learn all about jQuery Selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Here is a link to a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6ZBx7/ showing very basic usage. YOu will notice if you type in the box and press the button the text is copied to the textarea. For demo purposes also added another event handler of mousedown that clears the textarea. This is to show using different handlers on the same element using selectors.

Note the ids dont contain the '#' in Html. The '#' selector tells jquery to find all elemetns that match the ID. Similarily you can use the '.' selector (ie .myClass) to find all elements that have a specific class.

Comment: so the 
c.addEventListener('mouseup', onmouseup, false);

would still stay the same then ?

Comment: No, as an object selected by jquery is not the same as a document object. You can use the addEvent listener but you need to convert the jQuery object back to a DomObject. Have a look here for binding definitions. http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: See the thing is i want no traces of dom at all. Is that possible ?

Comment: To do this you will have to use the jQuery bind, on, click, mouseup etc in place of your Dom handlers. I would suggest playing around with jQuery. JSFiddle provides a simple way to load and edit html, javascript and css.

Comment: I changed it 
var x = $('#x');

x.mouseup(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();


});

but now it cannot access the "#x" file form the css

Comment: added a jsfiddle with basic usage of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

First one:

```
var x = $('#x')
```

(Note however that the result is not EXACTLY the same, $(...) retuns jQuery objects that are wrapped around the DOM objects.

Second one:

```
function onmouseup(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    //random code
}
c.on ("mouseup", onmouseup);
```

(Note that c, here, has to be a jQuery object, not the dome node. To create one from a DOM node, use `var jQUeryWrapped = $(plainDomNode)`.

Comment: is it possible to have no traces of Dom at all

Comment: What do you mean by that? jQuery only encapsulates DOM obejcts, they're of cours there. How are you supposed to work with the DOM tree without working with its members?

Comment: @user2990259: Yes, turn off your computer.